# How can I create local package in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yarn-workspaces, npm-package, yarn-link

I have main React typescript project and trying to create 3 local packages inside the project our of src folder and inside local_packages folder. The goal is whenever changes are made in these local packages, different dev pull changes, do yarn install and get all those changes in node_modules of the main project. Inside local packages, I've done yarn install and yarn link, then in main project directory, I did yarn link "local_package_name". I also have added local path in main package.json like this..

```
"player-impl": "file:./local_packages/player-impl",
```

this actually put the local player-imp package inside node_modules of the main project, but since I have done yarn link, main project files import data from local_package path instead of node_modules. So yarn link is useless for my scenario? How about yarn workspaces?